# Google Analytics - Show Users With 'X' Event But Without 'Y' Event

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api

I've just started using google analytics, and except of a quick beginners tutorial I don't know very much :-).
I have a website with few steps in the sign-up page. In the first step the user verifies his phone number. I want to have a list of all the users phones that completed the verification step but didn't finish the registration. In order to do this I send the following events in each step:

1. {eventAction: 'registration phase1', 'eventLabel': userPhoneNumber}.
2. {eventAction: 'registration phase2', 'eventLabel': userPhoneNumber}.
3. {eventAction: 'registration phase3', 'eventLabel': userPhoneNumber}.

I want to create a report that shows me all the phone numbers of the users who fired the first event but didn't fire the third event. I tried to achieve this by using event advanced filters with include and exclude condition but it seems that data being shown is not correct. I also tried to do this using the Query Explorer but I couldn't find out how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by first using the Google Analytics web UI to [create a segment](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3124493?hl=en&ref_topic=3123779). You can learn more [about segments here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123951?hl=en).

You'd want to use "include" and "exclude" sessions or users depending on your need. The setup will look something like this, adjust the events action/category/label as you wish to match the events you want. 
[image]

Save your segment and head over to the [Query Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/).
Select the appropriate property and view which you created the segment. Under the "segment" field type in the name of the segment you just created like so:
[image]

Fill in the rest of the form with the dates, dimensions/metrics that you want and you should get results according to that segment. No additional filtering needed.

Comment: Is it possible to save the query as a report in google analytics ? or I always need to use the Query Explorer to view this query?

Comment: You can create a custom report right in the Web UI: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1151300?hl=en